# Set Associated Content Type fields for a List Item

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, csom

My goal is to set a list item's Content Type to "Page Layout" and under "Associated Content Type" settings, Set "Content Type Group" to "Page Layout Content Types" and "Content Type Name" to "Article Page" for Office 365 SharePoint.

I am trying to accomplish this using CSOM and so far I was able to set Content Type to "Page Layout" but not the Associated Content Types.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to do it all at once?  If you change the content type of an item you may have to get a fresh reference to it to be able to access the unique fields of the new content type.

Comment: How many ever steps it takes. I only care that this is complete.

Answer (score 1):

For those who is still looking for the answer, it's here: [Here](https://lionadi.wordpress.com/2016/03/24/how-to-set-o365-pagelayout-associated-content-type-field/).

The value must be in the following format:

```
contentTypeAssociativeID = String.Format(";#{0};#{1};#", contentType.Name, contentType.StringId);
```